# Kentico | Upgrade tool fails to find website sln file

Tags: kentico

I am having difficulty using the upgrade tool for my website which is version 7.0.5354.21135 in my attempts to upgrade to version 10.

I ran the Kentico Upgrade\CodeUpgrade100\Tool>CodeUpgrade.exe file on my sln project file but it returned the following error 'Solution file not found'. I have changed the file structure of my project and the name and location of the CMS folder which might be the cause? (I directed cmd prompt to new file name/location i.e. not the inetpub/wwwroot folder)

I also tried to reinstall Kentico 7 and its 7.0.53 Hotfix in an attempt to upgrade a fresh install but my installation failed.

I am trying to upgrade my local development site from 7.0.5354.21135 up to 10 to test if any issues would result in such an upgrade (plan to do so in near future with live site).

**UPDATE:**

I moved files back to original inetpub folder and renamed sln project to 'WebProject.sln' but am still seeing the following error:

[image]

This is a newly created sln project file from original site files in VS13. Do I have to alter something else to get this new sln project file to work?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

For v7 if you made changes to your solution as a whole meaning, moving your .sln file outside of the root of the website, you will need to modify your solution to place it back in there.  Also make sure your .sln file is either named "WebProject.sln" or "WebApp.sln"

Comment: Thx Brendan, I updated my question with new error after latest attempt to resolve

Comment: Check the release notes for version 10 if I remember right it only supports Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Thx, I'm actually upgrading 7.0 - 8.0 and so on first (should've mentioned sry). But maybe in the 8.0 release notes there's a similar story with VS2013?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to download a fresh version7 install, copy across my local dev site files, open in VS and resave WebProject.sln or equivalent project. Then I built project and refactored through various redundant member objects removed from version 8